# WIFI works, but ubuntu does not see my network

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

In my main computer, running Ubuntu 18.04, I can connect normally to my home network.

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on another computer, the network is working, It can see my neighbors` wifi networks but it does not display my home network on the networks list.

I have already tried vanilla Ubuntu and Ubuntu Mate and this is happening on both distros.
Does anybody have a clue of what might be happening?

Here the output of `lspci -nnk`, since `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net` wields no output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Microsoft Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [1414:0154]
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Microsoft Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [1414:0166]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Microsoft Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [1414:1e31]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Microsoft Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller [1414:1e3a]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Microsoft Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [1414:1e2d]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Microsoft Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [1414:1e20]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Microsoft Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [1414:1e26]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e57] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Microsoft Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [1414:1e57]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Microsoft Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1414:1e03]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Microsoft Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [1414:1e22]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`  I smell a Broadcom wifi card

Comment: What channel is your home network on?

Comment: It was on channel 13, a switched to auto and now I was able to connect from Ubuntu Mate. Thank you

Comment: What about results for `dmesg | grep brcm`